# Why the returned value comes as 'undefined' in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that would return and store certain data in the variable. 
The code I'm trying is following. The code below is supposed to take xml file, parse it to json and then return set of values based on jp query.

```js
export function getEntities(testFileContent) {
    parseString(testFileContent, async function (err, result) {
        const entities = await jp.query(result, '$..entity_name[0]');
        return entities;
    });
}
```

The entities variable is being correctly filled inside the function but when trying to get the data like this, it comes as 'undefined':

```js
const data = await getEntities(testFileContent);
console.log(data) //will come as undefined
```

Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, it just calls a function called `parseString` and discards its return value after doing some callback work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't return anything, so its undefined. It's not a problem with typescript.

You just didn't realize that you return it inside an anonymous function so it's getting discarded.

I will make you an stackblitz example in a sec.

**UPDATE**

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kyuhca

I hope this will work for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try it later this evening and let know if worked!

Comment: In the end I wasn't really sure on how to adapt you solution to my case. However I've found different solution that I'm posting, Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I figure out on how to approach it. This is how I handled the xml to json conversion in the way I can extract the cllback from the function and it's possible to reuse it somewhere else. Probably quite basic thing but maybe someone faces the same impediments:

```
export function xmlToJSON(str, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseString(str, options, (err, jsonObj) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(jsonObj);
        });
    });
}
```

After that I simply call it and store the data in variable:

```
const json = await xmlToJSON(string, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function don't return anything

try

```
export async function getEntities(testFileContent) {
    return await parseString(testFileContent, async function (err, result) {
        const entities = await jp.query(result, '$..entity_name[0]');
        return entities;
    });
}
```

Comment: In fact that is not returning 'undefined'. However it returns the parsestring function instead of entities.